# Can I programmatically trigger Touch ID enablement process?

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

After calling `[laContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]` and finding out through the error code that the device has hardware support for Touch ID, but that it hasn't been enabled or no fingers have been enrolled, is there a way that I can trigger the iOS dialog to enable/enroll from within my app?

Comment: No. The best you can do it suggest to the user to enable it if they want. But it is up to the user to enable it or not. No app can force it.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the response. I didn't think I could force the enablement/enrollment, but I thought perhaps I could bring up the iOS preferences/settings dialog. Just to confirm, you're saying that I cannot even do that, right?

Comment: There's no API to do it and there is no way to launch the Settings app (other than your own app's page).